# Dynamic <apex:inputHidden> fields

Tags: apex, visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

I am trying to create a small VF page which displays a set of dynamic fields.  Here is the controller:

```
public class dynFields1 {

public final Case casex {set;get;}

    public dynFields1(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        casex = (Case) controller.getRecord();
        dfs = new List<String> () ;
dfs.add('field1__c') ;
dfs.add('field2__c');
dfs.add('field3__c');
       }


public String [] dfs {set;get;}
```

For the VF, I can now dynamically display input fields:

```
<apex:page standardController="Case"  extensions="dynFields1">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageBlockButtons >
<apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
<apex:repeat value="{!dfs}" var="df">
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
<apex:inputField value="{!casex[df]}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:repeat>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

But I also need to add  fields, otherwise I get the usual "Object row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field" error.  So I tried to add them using the same syntax:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!dfs}" var="df">
<apex:inputHidden value="{!casex[df]}"/>
</apex:repeat>
```

But this gives me the ""Object row was retrieved via SOQL without ..." error.  As of now, I have to hard code the dynamic fields:

```
<apex:inputHidden value="{!Case.field1__c}"/>
<apex:inputHidden value="{!Case.field2__c}"/>
<apex:inputHidden value="{!Case.field3__c}"/>
```

and then it works fine.  So is there a way to set the  fields dynamically?

Comment: Have you tried using [`StandardController.addFields`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_ApexPages_StandardController_addFields.htm)?

Comment: The Fox Strikes!  Many thanks, looks like I still have a lot to learn!